# Why does the flutter folder have an error

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have this problem where in the flutter folder having some error but it does not affect on my project. its just that it slows down the vscode and might cause future error in my future projects.

[image: picture of the error in flutter folder]

Comment: Please go in pubspec.yaml file and do 'pub get'. then try to run your code. I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function should be in the file `main.dart` under the top level `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. An error doesn't affect your application because it seems like this file is not used in your main project.
2. import 'package:test/test.dart'; doesn't exist which means you might be not added in pubsec.yml file or didn't sync it properly(put get).
3. https://pub.dev/packages/test go here to check how to implement and use it or if you don't need it for now just remove it or comment it.